# Android - Java: how to draw a straight line slowly

Tags: java, android, draw, gesture

I can't draw a straight line slowly!
when I slide slowly I have a wavy line instead a straight line.

I tried to use the tool "Pointer location" to check the points and I recived the same result.
But when I slide fastly, vertical, or horizontal, I recived straight line...

This is my code

```
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String ms;
    switch (event.getAction()){
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
        int xDown = (int)event.getX();
        int yDown =  (int)event.getY();

        ms = "down";
        out.println(xDown);
        out.println(yDown);
        out.println(ms);

        break;
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
        ms = "move";

        int hsize = event.getHistorySize(); 
        for(int i=0;i<hsize;i++)
        {
            int x = (int)event.getHistoricalX(i);
            int y = (int)event.getHistoricalY(i);
            int hx = x;
            int hy = y;
            out.println(hx);
            out.println(hy);
            out.println(ms);
        }

        /*
        int xMove =  (int)event.getX();
        int yMove =  (int)event.getY();
        out.println(xMove);
        out.println(yMove);
        ms = "move";
        out.println(ms);
        */
        break;
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
        int xUp = (int)event.getX();
        int yUp =  (int)event.getY();
        out.println(xUp);
        out.println(yUp);
        ms = "up";
        out.println(ms);
        break;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: You can draw a straight line when moving quickly because each touch event is spread out and you're drawing a line between two points.  When you move fast, those points are spread out and the straight part of the line is more visible.  When you move slowly, the same number of touch events are being registered but they're all much closer together.  This means that you'll have several straight line segments forming your line really close together so the line will appear jagged.  To solve this? Move your finger faster or throw away touch events if you haven't moved far enough.

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest you to save starting location and redraw line each time from the starting point to the point where you are touching the screen.

If you don't want a polygon made of straight lines you can draw it by tapping the screen where you want to place next point.